# My Xcode installation is taking up loads of space; how to reduce space used by simulators?

Tags: xcode, diskspace

So my computer is the base model MacBook Pro so hard drive space is a premium.

I've been looking through folders to find what's taking up all the space and my `UserName/Library/Developer` folder was 30GB. This folder contains `Xcode` & `CoreSimulator`.

I've gone and deleted most of my archived projects and that's reduced the size down to 20GB in total with 18GB in the Xcode folder, but this still seems large.

I haven't got any of the simulators installed, except for the current 8.4 simulator, yet I seem to have a folder for each simulator in the iOS DeviceSupport subfolder of Xcode.

Can someone tell me if their Xcode folder is a similar size and if I should expect all of the simulators to be included in this folder, even if they aren't visibly available in Xcode? Is it safe for me to delete all of these unused simulators?

Comment: For me xcode app took 6.33 Gb of memory

Comment: Even for me developers folders occupied 30Gb!!

Comment: mine is 24.4 GB! .. what is ideal size for this folder ?

Comment: Use the free GrandPerspective application to find disk usage and remove unneeded files.

Comment: For me, between /Library/Developer, ~/Library/Developer, /Applications/XCode.app, over 40Gb

Comment: My /Applications/XCode.app is 9GB+, is it normal? Is it possible to reduce the size?

Comment: @Liuting - Yes, I have Xcode 7.2, after all kinds of clean up, still taking up over 9GB. So, I guess that's par for the course. Still too huge.

Comment: [On which site is “My Xcode installation is taking up loads of space; how to reduce space used by simulators?” on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367707/on-which-site-is-my-xcode-installation-is-taking-up-loads-of-space-how-to-redu)

Comment: Which version of MacOS? of Xcode? Btw, I think this should be migrated to [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com) or else [SuperUser](https://superuser.com)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to remove all the simulators.

Your best option is probably just to install again Xcode, this way you could just `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer` and `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer` then install again everything (a simple download that is.)

Comment: .. and get back "error `/Library/Developer` is a directory".

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm sure nobody would've a problem figuring out what to do but thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out you can run the following command in terminal to delete unused simulators and free up some space:

```
xcrun simctl delete unavailable
```